# WebStorm Run icon missing in the gutter

Tags: debugging, ide, webstorm

[image]

I was looking something like this:
[image]

Here is my file structures
[image]
[image]

Comment: what does your package.json look like, how many package.json  files do you have in your project? The logic used for determining what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in package.json nearest to current file. If none are found, there will be no icons in the gutter

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I never thought that package.json had an impact on icons in the gutter. It turned out that I missed the mocha dependency in the "devDependencies"(I used the globally installed mocha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic used for determining what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json`. Declaring `"mocha"` as a dependency in `<project root>/package.json` should enable mocha runner in `<project root>/**/*` files. 
Note that if Mocha is not installed locally/included in `package.json`, you can create a **Mocha** run configuration with *All in directory* selected and specify a directory where your spec files are located. In this case, right-click on a test file inside this directory will suggest to run with Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by missing mocha in my npm dependencies. Maybe there is a way to tell Webstorm to look for the globally installed mocha.